# C++ Linked List Compilation Error

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have the following cpp files and h file. These were examples given to us by the instructor but do not want to compile. I keep getting this error:

```
linked_list.cpp:50:6: error: prototype for ‘void     LinkedList::remove(LinkedListNode*, int*)’ does not match any in class     ‘LinkedList’
 void LinkedList::remove(LinkedListNode *node, int *return_value) {
      ^
In file included from linked_list.cpp:1:0:
linked_list.h:31:7: error: candidate is: void      LinkedList::remove(LinkedListNode*)
  void remove(LinkedListNode *node);
       ^
```

here is the code:

```
#include "linked_list.h"

LinkedList::LinkedList() {
    this->start = NULL;
    this->end = NULL;
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList() {
    LinkedListNode *current = this->start;
    while (current != NULL) {
        LinkedListNode *temp = current;
        current = current->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}

void LinkedList::push(int val) {
    LinkedListNode *new_node = new LinkedListNode();
    new_node->value = val;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    new_node->prev = this->end;

    if (this->end != NULL) {
        this->end->next = new_node;
    } else {
        this->start = new_node;
    }

    this->end = new_node;
}

int LinkedList::peek() {
    if (this->end != NULL) {
        return this->end->value;
    }

    return -1;
}

int LinkedList::pop() {
    if (this->end != NULL) {
        int val = this->end->value;
        remove(this->end);
        return val;
    }

    return -1;
}

void LinkedList::remove(LinkedListNode *node, int *return_value) {
    if (this->start == node) {
        this->start = node->next;
    } else if (node->prev != NULL) {
        node->prev->next = node->next;
    }

    if (this->end == node) {
        this->end = node->prev;
    } else if (node->next != NULL) {
        node->next->prev = node->prev;
    }

    delete node;
}
```

Here is the header file:

```
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct LinkedListNode
{
    LinkedListNode *prev;
    LinkedListNode *next;
    int value;
};

class LinkedList
{
 public:
   LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();

    void push(int val);
    bool insert_at(int val, int idx);

    int peek();
    int pop();
    int retrieve_at(int idx);
    bool remove_at(int idx);

    LinkedListNode *find(int val);

private:
    LinkedListNode *start;
    LinkedListNode *end;

    void remove(LinkedListNode *node);
};
```

here is the main file:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "linked_list.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    LinkedList list;
    list.push(5);

    cout << list.peek() << endl;
    cout << list.pop() << endl;
    cout << list.pop() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void remove(LinkedListNode *node);` in your header doesn't match `void LinkedList::remove(LinkedListNode *node, int *return_value) {` in your code.

Comment: Which part of the error message is unclear? You declare `remove` to take one parameter, but you attempt to implement it as taking two parameters.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'm not sure if this should be an answer, or we simply should close that question for a trivial mistake.

Comment: i understand that, i tried changing the parameters but still does not work. Again, this is not my code. This is code posted by the instructor as a linked list example for us to study but does not work. I just want to make sure that it is not my compiler version that is the cause.

Comment: _@lrod408_ No, it's not a matter of your compiler version. Just as @Igor already pointed out.

Comment: It's clearly a typo. `return_value` is never actually used in the implementation of `remove()` Just get rid of it in the parameter list.

Comment: And tell your instructor -- tactfully -- that this code is incorrect.

Comment: i did, and the errors get worst. Ill just ask the instructor. I really wanted to make sure that it wasn't my compiler. Now I know that it is not.

Answer (score 2):

It is really easy.. If you would just read the errors you could see what is wrong, it even tells you where. Look at the header file where the function `remove` is declared. Then look at the cpp file where the function `remove` is defined.  You should see that when the function gets declared it has one more Parameter of type int* called `return_value`. This Parameter is missing at the definition of the function. You just have to add the parameter to the definition in the cpp file ( or remove it from the declaration)

Answer (score 2):

For this error,

> linked_list.cpp:50:6: error: prototype for ‘void
>   LinkedList::remove(LinkedListNode*, int*)’ does not match any in class
>   ‘LinkedList’  void LinkedList::remove(LinkedListNode *node, int
>   *return_value) {

the issue is that the remove function that is defined in the .cpp (code) does not match any of those functions declared in the header (.h file). To fix, change the remove function in the header (.h file) to the following:

```
//    void remove(LinkedListNode *node); // Wrong
    void remove(LinkedListNode *node, int*);
```

And in the .cpp file, change the pop() function to:

```
int LinkedList::pop() {
    if (this->end != NULL) {
//        int val = this->end->value; // Wrong 
//        remove(this->end); // Wrong
        int val; // new
        remove(this->end, &val); // new
```

The next compile error is complaining about the same issues but in a different way. It is complaining that the remove function declared in the header has no definition, which makes sense because they didn't match. So the fix that is already made will fix both compile errors.

Comment: Thanks for your help. All I really had to do was match the parameters. I was still getting errors after fixing the parameters but not because of the code. I was getting errors because I was compiling them wrong via terminal. I'm using gcc/g++ on linux. My problem was that I was not linking the object files to the main file. That is why it was not working. I researched it and figured out how to do this. Sorry for this this type of question but I'm new to C++. So far, I like JAVA better.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. It'll get better! :)